# Second order differential equation at an ordinary point, Frobenius method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the eq:

$$(x+2)y''-xy'+(1-x^2)y=0 ; \quad X_0=1$$

I get to this step after deriving the derivatives of the $\sum_0^\infty A_n(x-1)^n$ :

$$(1+(x-1))\left[ \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (n(n-1)A_n(x-1)^{n-2}\right]-(1+(x-1))\left[\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} A_nn(x-1)^{n-1}\right] + (1-x^2)\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n(x-1)^n\right)=0$$

After distributing through what I could:

$\sum n(n-1)A_n(x-1)^{n-2} +\sum n(n-1)A_n(x-1)^{n-1}-\sum A_nn(x-1)^{n-1}-\sum A_n(x-1)^n+(1-x^2)\cdot \sum A_n(x-1)^n =0$

I don't understand how to distribute through the last piece $(1-x^2)$ as I do for the first piece where I substituted $(1+(x-1))$ to make it possible.

How would I go about solving the rest?
Help is appreciated; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's simpler if you start with a change of variables $s = x - 1$, so your differential equation becomes 
$$ (s+3) y'' - (s + 1) y' - (s^2 + 2 s) y = 0$$
Now with $y = \sum_n A_n s^n$ you'll get, e.g. for the last term
$$ - (s^2 + 2 s) \sum_n A_n s^n = - \sum_n A_n s^{n+2} - 2 \sum_n A_n s^{n+1}$$

Comment: Sometimes I guess I just like to torture myself by over-thinking things, thanks a bunch Robert!